# Is it possible to have two or more context bound classes in Scala

Tags: scala, context-bound

How do I specify that I need e.g. a ClassTag AND an Ordering for T?

Example

`def sort[T: ClassTag <and> Ordering](future: Future[Seq[T]]): Future[Seq[T]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def sort[T: ClassTag : Ordering](future: Future[Seq[T]]): Future[Seq[T]]
```

as briefly discussed in the [language reference](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), section 7.4